# Configure Burst Sends in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, configuration, email-studio, send-email

Do any of you have any experience with Burst Sending in Marketing Cloud? I'd like to know more about this feature to be able to send email faster and to improve email delivery speed for highly dynamic emails. If so, can you help me to answer some of my questions below (I have been looking for some documentation about the Burst Sending but there are only a few of them.)

- Can you share the pro and cons of using this add-on feature?
- Is it only available in Content Builder email sends and the Automation Studio Send Email activity and not in Journey Builder?
- How to configure it?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Its a paid feature and yes its only available through automation sends. You should talk to your account team to see if your use case would benefit from it

Answer (score 0):

As it's an old feature and Salesforce keeps updating (and losing) much valuable documentation over time. It's one of the features that doesn't have much official information available at the moment.

- PRO: it does what it's supposed to. A send that normally could take many hours will be completed in minutes
- PRO: it works just fine with Automation Studio sends
- CON: tracking data is still slow to get back to SFMC, so if you send out 1m messages at once you will still wait for a while until delivery statuses are populated

It couldn't work with Journey Builder anyhow since it processes on Contact-by-Contact basis and not really intended as a way to blast one message to a massive audience at the same time.

In addition, I would highlight that there is also a feature called **[Delayed Delivery](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000339825&type=1)** that works together with Burst Sending to build everything for the scheduled send.